# Sorting multiple columns in a full outer join, possibly containing NULLs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, join, order-by

I am trying to compare a plan against a history to see if there are steps omitted or if unplanned steps have been included. The regular, planned history items as well as the anomalies are intended for an elaborate report. The problem is, I have a column in each joined table that I need for sorting, but due to the `full outer join` I cannot guarantee them to be `not null`, which breaks sorting. I'll continue with a simplified example, where the plan corresponds to a recipe:

```
Table: RecipeSteps

 Id | RecipeId | Position | Message
----+----------+----------+----------------------------
 50 |      123 |        1 | Wash vegetables
 51 |      123 |        2 | Peel vegetables
 52 |      123 |        3 | Cut meat
 53 |      123 |        4 | Turn on stove
 54 |      123 |        5 | Cook and stir it
 55 |      123 |        6 | Turn off stove
----+----------+----------+----------------------------
```

... and the history to the actual steps while cooking:

```
Table: History

 Id | TimeStamp | Session | StepId | Message
----+-----------+---------+--------+-----------------------------
 90 |  00:01:00 |     321 |   NULL | Chef entered kitchen
 91 |  00:02:00 |     321 |     51 | Chef peeled vegetables
 92 |  00:03:00 |     321 |     52 | Chef cut meat
 93 |  00:04:00 |     321 |   NULL | Chef picked his nose
 94 |  00:05:00 |     321 |     53 | Chef turned on stove
 95 |  00:06:00 |     321 |     54 | Chef started cooking
 96 |  00:10:00 |     321 |   NULL | Chef left kitchen
 97 |  01:00:00 |     321 |   NULL | FIRE!
----+-----------+---------+--------+-----------------------------
```

Now, I want to compare these tables in a result table with a `full outer join` similar to this:

```
Table: Result

 Sorting | TimeStamp | Position | Message                | Comment
 --------+-----------+----------+------------------------+---------------
       1 |  00:01:00 |     NULL | Chef entered kitchen   | unplanned
       2 |      NULL |        1 | Wash vegetables        | omitted
       3 |  00:02:00 |        2 | Chef peeled vegetables | planned
       4 |  00:03:00 |        3 | Chef cut meat          | planned
       5 |  00:04:00 |     NULL | Chef picked his nose   | unplanned
       6 |  00:05:00 |        4 | Chef turned on stove   | planned
       7 |  00:06:00 |        5 | Chef started cooking   | planned
       8 |      NULL |        6 | Turn off stove         | omitted
       9 |  00:10:00 |     NULL | Chef left kitchen      | unplanned
      10 |  01:00:00 |     NULL | FIRE!                  | unplanned
 --------+-----------+----------+------------------------+---------------
```

Then the reader of the report sees:

- Entering/leaving the kitchen is not part of the recipe, but it has been recorded anyway.
- The chef forgot to wash the vegetables (Ugh!) or the step has not been recorded for some reason (Phew!).
- History continues as planned, with the exception of the chef picking his nose in between (double-Ugh!)
- The chef forgot to turn off the stove, which caused the fire, in the end.

I came up with the following `SELECT` statement, selecting from this query with `ORDER BY Sorting ASC`, but I still have a problem to fill the `Sorting` criterion:

```
SELECT
  0 Sorting, -- this has to be replaced
  h.TimeStamp,
  r.Position,
  '...' Message, -- case-when-construct, not important for the question
  '...' Comment -- case-when-construct, not important for the question
FROM RecipeSteps r
FULL OUTER JOIN History h
ON h.StepId = r.Id
WHERE (r.RecipeId = 123 OR r.RecipeId IS NULL)
AND (h.Session = 321 OR h.Session IS NULL)
```

There is a natural order in the history given by the timestamps and one in the recipe given by the `Position` column. As they are never both `null` simultaneously, I could create the `Sorting` column based on these, but I couldn't figure out, so far, how to achieve this.

I know I can sort both separately, enumerate and compare both sequences etc. programmatically, but I'm curious if this is also possible with non-procedural SQL.

Comment: Odds are reasonable that you could use a `CASE` statement to set the `Sorting` values and/or windowing functions. Unfortunately, it's not clear how that would happen with the data as shown. How do you know where to place a skipped `RecipeStep`, relative to "unplanned" `History` rows? What if the `History` rows and the `RecipeSteps` rows don't follow the same order? How should that impact the placement of skipped steps? For instance, id the chef cut the meat, then peeled the veggies, should the skipped "wash the veggies" precede or follow cutting the meat?

Comment: Maybe the example is a bit oversimplified at that point: In the actual problem, there is no alternative order. We can safely assume no steps are swapped. However, such swapping events could generate `omitted` as well as `unplanned` rows for each of the swapped rows, if needed. The regular entries (both not null) are kind of "anchor-points", where the sequences could be "synchronized" and the rest is ordered by timestamp or position, repectively. I'll rethink the `CASE` statements I had and have a look at windowing functions, tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note: The query below doesn't take into account partitioning by `Session` to keep it simple.

The main idea is to split the data set into two groups and process them separately. `History` goes first. I decided to make `History` more important than `Steps`. If some steps are swapped, they will be presented in the history order.

So, the first group is all rows from `History` plus possible details from the corresponding Step. This is a simple `LEFT JOIN`.

The second group is omitted Steps. Another `LEFT JOIN` with a filter.

If you run the first `CTE_History` ordering by timestamp you'll see that unplanned events have `NULL` `Position`, but they will be in correct position in the result set, because of their timestamp. All we need to do is fill in these blanks.

```
+-------------+---------------------+----------+------------------------+-----------+
| NewPosition |         ts          | Position |       NewMessage       |  Comment  |
+-------------+---------------------+----------+------------------------+-----------+
|           0 | 2017-01-01 00:01:00 | NULL     | Chef entered kitchen   | unplanned |
|           2 | 2017-01-01 00:02:00 | 2        | Chef peeled vegetables | planned   |
|           3 | 2017-01-01 00:03:00 | 3        | Chef cut meat          | planned   |
|           3 | 2017-01-01 00:04:00 | NULL     | Chef picked his nose   | unplanned |
|           4 | 2017-01-01 00:05:00 | 4        | Chef turned on stove   | planned   |
|           5 | 2017-01-01 00:06:00 | 5        | Chef started cooking   | planned   |
|           5 | 2017-01-01 00:10:00 | NULL     | Chef left kitchen      | unplanned |
|           5 | 2017-01-01 01:00:00 | NULL     | FIRE!                  | unplanned |
+-------------+---------------------+----------+------------------------+-----------+
```

One way to do it is to take the last non-null value from the previous rows. Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't implement `IGNORE NULLS` clause in the `LAST_VALUE` function, so we have to use a workaround with `MAX` and rely on the fact that `Position` grows as `ts` grows. In a more general case it will be a bit more complicated, as Itzik Ben-Gan showed in his [The Last non NULL Puzzle](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/last-non-null-puzzle).

The very first `NULL` is changed to `0` (or some number that is less than any possible Position).

Once we have values for all Positions, it is trivial to union this result with all omitted steps and order them.

In this approach all omitted steps go after unplanned steps in case of ambiguity, so `Turn off stove` will appear last. If you choose to calculate `MIN` of following rows instead of `MAX` of previous, this rule will be swapped.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @RecipeSteps TABLE (Id int, RecipeId int, Position int, Message nvarchar(255));
INSERT INTO @RecipeSteps (Id, RecipeId, Position, Message) VALUES
(50, 123, 1, 'Wash vegetables '),
(51, 123, 2, 'Peel vegetables '), --
(52, 123, 3, 'Cut meat        '), --
(53, 123, 4, 'Turn on stove   '), --
(54, 123, 5, 'Cook and stir it'), --
(55, 123, 6, 'Turn off stove  ');

DECLARE @History TABLE (Id int, ts datetime2(0), Session int, StepId int, Message nvarchar(255));
INSERT INTO @History (Id, ts, Session, StepId, Message) VALUES
(90, '2017-01-01 00:01:00', 321, NULL, 'Chef entered kitchen  '),
(91, '2017-01-01 00:02:00', 321,   51, 'Chef peeled vegetables'),
(92, '2017-01-01 00:03:00', 321,   52, 'Chef cut meat         '),
(93, '2017-01-01 00:04:00', 321, NULL, 'Chef picked his nose  '),
(94, '2017-01-01 00:05:00', 321,   53, 'Chef turned on stove  '),
(95, '2017-01-01 00:06:00', 321,   54, 'Chef started cooking  '),
(96, '2017-01-01 00:10:00', 321, NULL, 'Chef left kitchen     '),
(97, '2017-01-01 01:00:00', 321, NULL, 'FIRE!                 ');
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_History
AS
(
    SELECT
        ISNULL(
            MAX(Position) 
            OVER (ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
            , 0) AS NewPosition
        ,H.ts
        ,S.Position
        ,H.Message AS NewMessage
        ,CASE WHEN S.Id IS NULL THEN 'unplanned' ELSE 'planned' END AS Comment
    FROM
        @History AS H
        LEFT JOIN @RecipeSteps AS S ON S.Id = H.StepId
)
,CTE_OmittedSteps
AS
(
    SELECT
        Position AS NewPosition
        ,H.ts
        ,S.Position
        ,S.Message AS NewMessage
        ,'omitted' AS Comment
    FROM
        @RecipeSteps AS S
        LEFT JOIN @History AS H ON S.Id = H.StepId
    WHERE
        H.Id IS NULL
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_History
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE_OmittedSteps
ORDER BY NewPosition, ts;
```

**Result**

```
+-------------+---------------------+----------+------------------------+-----------+
| NewPosition |         ts          | Position |       NewMessage       |  Comment  |
+-------------+---------------------+----------+------------------------+-----------+
|           0 | 2017-01-01 00:01:00 | NULL     | Chef entered kitchen   | unplanned |
|           1 | NULL                | 1        | Wash vegetables        | omitted   |
|           2 | 2017-01-01 00:02:00 | 2        | Chef peeled vegetables | planned   |
|           3 | 2017-01-01 00:03:00 | 3        | Chef cut meat          | planned   |
|           3 | 2017-01-01 00:04:00 | NULL     | Chef picked his nose   | unplanned |
|           4 | 2017-01-01 00:05:00 | 4        | Chef turned on stove   | planned   |
|           5 | 2017-01-01 00:06:00 | 5        | Chef started cooking   | planned   |
|           5 | 2017-01-01 00:10:00 | NULL     | Chef left kitchen      | unplanned |
|           5 | 2017-01-01 01:00:00 | NULL     | FIRE!                  | unplanned |
|           6 | NULL                | 6        | Turn off stove         | omitted   |
+-------------+---------------------+----------+------------------------+-----------+
```

**Query for SQL Server 2008**

Here I replaced the window function `MAX` with a subquery that I put into `OUTER APPLY`. It produces the same result as above.

```
WITH
CTE_HistoryRaw
AS
(
    SELECT
        H.ts
        ,S.Position
        ,H.Message AS NewMessage
        ,CASE WHEN S.Id IS NULL THEN 'unplanned' ELSE 'planned' END AS Comment
    FROM
        @History AS H
        LEFT JOIN @RecipeSteps AS S ON S.Id = H.StepId
)
,CTE_History
AS
(
    SELECT
        ISNULL(A.NewPosition, 0) AS NewPosition
        ,ts
        ,Position
        ,NewMessage
        ,Comment
    FROM
        CTE_HistoryRaw AS Curr
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP(1)
                Prev.Position AS NewPosition
            FROM CTE_HistoryRaw AS Prev
            WHERE
                Prev.ts <= Curr.ts
                AND Prev.Position IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY Prev.ts DESC
        ) AS A
)
,CTE_OmittedSteps
AS
(
    SELECT
        Position AS NewPosition
        ,H.ts
        ,S.Position
        ,S.Message AS NewMessage
        ,'omitted' AS Comment
    FROM
        @RecipeSteps AS S
        LEFT JOIN @History AS H ON S.Id = H.StepId
    WHERE
        H.Id IS NULL
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_History
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE_OmittedSteps
ORDER BY NewPosition, ts;
```

Comment: @ChrisTophski, with SQL Server 2008 at the very least you should have an index on a `timestamp` column, but on a big table a cursor may be faster. Cursor is `O(n)`, subquery is `O(n*n)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll try that later. First, I have to fix an issue, where not all rows are returned as expected. Some of the omitted steps are missing in the result, but I already had that problem in my first approach with the full outer join, so I think the problem must be a logical error in my filter criteria. But that is not related to this question.